# Django: Detect unused templates

Tags: python, django, refactoring, code-cleanup

Is there a way to detect unused templates in a Django project?

Before Django 1.3, that would have been possible with a simple string-matching function like [this one](https://github.com/AMeng/django-unused-templates). But since 1.3, there are generic class based views that automatically generate a `template_name`, if you don't override it (e.g. DetailView).

Also, if you override 3rd party module templates, those templates aren't used anywhere directly in your views.

Maybe it could be done by crawling all URL definitions, loading the corresponding views and getting the `template_name` from them?

Comment: If you're worried you aren't using templates generated from class based views, you are not using those views either (well unless you're overriding) I'd clean up the views :-)

Comment: @ArgsKwargs I don't really understand your comment. Anyways, I was thinking about a generic approach to this problem that works in any case. This is especially useful for legacy projects.

Comment: Django does not load unused templates. You don't need to worry about them at all

Comment: @ramusus I know, but I want to clean the project directory from old templates that aren't used anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to detect unused templates for certain, even in the absence of generic views, because you can always write code like this:

```
get_template(any_code_you_like()).render(context)
```

So even prior to Django 1.3 the django-unused-templates application you linked to could only have worked for projects that respected some kind of discipline about the use of templates. (For example, always having a string literal as the template argument to functions like `get_template` and `render_to_response`.)

Loading all the views wouldn't be sufficient either: a view may use different templates under different circumstances:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'template1.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'template2.html')
```

And of course templates may not be used by views at all, but by other parts of the system (for example, e-mail messages).

Comment: Thank you. I already expected that, but didn't know whether there might be a possibility I didn't think of :)

Answer (score 2):

I was curious if you could do this by monkey patching/decorating get_template instead.  I think you can, though you have to find all the template loading 
functions (I have two in my example below).

I used [wrapt](http://wrapt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) when I noticed it went beyond just loader.get_template, but it seems to the trick just fine.  Of course, keep this 50000 km away from prod, but...

Now, the thing to follow as well is that I am driving this with unittests and nosetests so, if you have full branch coverage of your template-using Python code, you should be able to get most templates (assuming I didn't miss any get_template-type functions).

in **settings.py**

This is the "brains" to patch get_template & co.

```
import wrapt
import django.template.loader
import django.template.engine

def wrapper(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):

    #concatenate the args vector into a string.
    # print "\n\n\n\n%s\nI am a wrapper \nusage:%s\n%s\n\n\n\n\n" % ("*"*80, usage, "*"*80)
    try:
        return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    finally:
        usage = ",".join([unicode(arg) for arg in args if arg])
        track_usage(usage)

#you have to wrap whatever is loading templates...
#imported django module + class/method/function path of what needs to be
#wrapped within that module.  comment those 2 lines out and you are back to
#normal


wrapt.wrap_function_wrapper(django.template.loader, 'get_template', wrapper)
wrapt.wrap_function_wrapper(django.template.engine, 'Engine.find_template', wrapper)
```

See [safely-applying-monkey-patches-in-python](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/03/safely-applying-monkey-patches-in-python.html) for more details on wrapt.  Actually easier to use than to understand the docs, decorators make my brain hurt.

Also, to track which django functions were doing the actual loads I mispelled some template names on purpose in the code and in templates, ran unit tests on it and looked at the stacktraces for missing template exceptions.

This is my rather badly-written function which adds to a set and puts it into
a json output....

```
def track_usage(usage):
    fnp_usage = "./usage.json"

    try:
        with open(fnp_usage, "r") as fi:
            data = fi.read()
            #read the set of used templates from the json file
            j_data = json.loads(data)
            s_used_file = set(j_data.get("li_used"))

    except (IOError,),e:
            s_used_file = set()
            j_data = dict()

    s_used_file.add(usage)
    #convert the set back to a list for json compatibility
    j_data["li_used"] = list(s_used_file)

    with open(fnp_usage, "w") as fo:
        json.dump(j_data, fo)
```

and the ouput (with a script to format it):

```
import sys
import json
fnp_usage = sys.argv[1]


with open(fnp_usage, "r") as fi:
    data = fi.read()
    #read the set of used templates from the json file
    j_data = json.loads(data)
    li_used_file = j_data.get("li_used")
    li_used_file.sort()

    print "\n\nused templates:"
    for t in li_used_file:
        print(t)
```

From wrapping the 2 functions above, it seems to have caught extends, %includes and straight get_templates, as well as list-type templates that were being used by class-based views.  It even caught my dynamically generated templates which aren't even on the file system but get loaded with a custom loader.

```
used templates:
bootstrap/display_form.html
bootstrap/errors.html
bootstrap/field.html
bootstrap/layout/baseinput.html
bootstrap/layout/checkboxselectmultiple.html
bootstrap/layout/field_errors.html
bootstrap/layout/field_errors_block.html
bootstrap/layout/help_text.html
bootstrap/layout/help_text_and_errors.html
bootstrap/layout/radioselect.html
bootstrap/whole_uni_form.html
django_tables2/table.html
dynamic_template:db:testdb:name:pssecurity/directive.PrimaryDetails.json
uni_form/layout/div.html
uni_form/layout/fieldset.html
websec/__base.html
websec/__full12.html
websec/__l_right_sidebar.html
websec/bootstrapped_home.html
websec/changedb.html
websec/login.html
websec/requirejs_config.html
websec/topnav.html
websec/user_msg.html
```